# Why only the first template will be reset if have multiple inheritance templates?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have 2 base templates and it was used a layout named **BasePage** :

> basetemplate1, basetemplate2

Another template named **mytemplate** with layout named **MyPage** and it will be inherited from basetemplate1, basetemplate2 (use Set Base Template..). Now **mytemplate** also have

1. basetemplate1
2. basetemplate2

Problem is: When I reset **mytemplate** via Standard Value. WHY the result is: 
Template: **BasePage**. Layout Details with controls: 1. basetemplate1. I mean just only the first template will be reset ?

Comment: what happened if you swap the order of the template in the inheritance sections? Does it choose the basetemplate2?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya, yes, it will choose basetemplate2.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post written by John West

> Standard values do not apply layout deltas. For example, if template X inherits from template A, template X will not store a layout delta for comparison against the layout details defined in the standard values of template A. Instead of storing the differences between the layout details in each standard values item, Sitecore copies layout details from the standard values of template A to the standard values of template X before applying the changes only to layout details in X.

So, to my understanding, since the **mytemplate** inherits both **basetemplate1** and **basetemplate2**, when resetting the Presentation, it will take the first template in the inheritance.

Reference: [John West Post](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/all-about-standard-values-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx)

Thanks

Comment: I dont think that is inheritance concept because basetemplate1 and basetemplate2 are parent of mytemplate.